# Python) How to convert string to dict? (Strange type of string)

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

The string is..

```
{
   "version":"20131101",
   "logo":"http://image.aladin.co.kr/img/header/2011/aladin_logo_new.gif",
   "title":"알라딘 베스트셀러 리스트 - 철학사",
   "link":"http:\/\/www.aladin.co.kr\/shop\/common\/wbest.aspx?BestType=Bestseller&amp;BranchType=1&amp;CID=51441&amp;Year=2019&amp;Month=5&amp;Week=4&amp;partner=openAPI",
   "pubDate":"Mon, 27 May 2019 10:33:33 GMT",
   "totalResults":955,
   "startIndex":1,
   "itemsPerPage":10,
   "query":"QueryType=BESTSELLER;CategoryId=51441;Year=2019;Month=5;Week=4",
   "searchCategoryId":51441,
   "searchCategoryName":"철학사",
   "item":[
      {
         "title":"처음 읽는 서양철학사 (개정증보판) - 서양의 대표 철학자 40인과 시작하는 철학의 첫걸음",
         "link":"http:\/\/www.aladin.co.kr\/shop\/wproduct.aspx?ItemId=100442130&amp;partner=openAPI&amp;start=api",
         "author":"안광복 (지은이)",

      }
   ]
}
```

I wanna convert string to dict.

This is what I want

1. I want to make this whole string to dictionary, So I want to get the value of "item"

   ```
   "item" : [{"title: ", " : ", ... }, {"title: ", " : ", ...  }, { "title: ", " : ", ... }]
   ```
2. I want the dictionaries(looks like dictionary but string) in the list(looks like list but str) so i want to use like dictionary

   ```
   print(decoding_bestseller.find("item",370))
   b=decoding_bestseller.split('"item"')
   want_str=b[1]
   want_str1=want_str.strip(':[]{}')
   want_list=want_str1.split(',')
   book_dic = {}
   for i in range(0,len(want_list)):
       in_colon = ":" in want_list[i]
       if in_colon:
           split_list = want_list[i].split(':')
           book_key = split_list[0].strip('""')
           book_value = split_list[1].strip('""')
           book_dic[book_key] = book_value
   ```

I did like that but I failed.

The string is like this
    `{" : ", " : ", "item : [ {"title : ", "link : ", } {"title : ", "link : ",  }, " : "}`

i want to make `{"title : ", "link : ", ...}` to REAL dictionary!

Comment: @crash did you mean `json.loads()` ?

Comment: I apologize @Nenri, that's what I meant. I'm deleting the useless comment

Comment: No prob, it can be confusing as in most of the other languages, it's a `.parse` method

Answer (score 2):

If your string is well written (no json error, you can check [there](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to correct your json), then you can use `json.loads(yourString)` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/json.html#json.loads))

Comment: @ziinaa feel free, but i advice you to post an other question, if it's a big issue

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from a string using `eval`.

```
as_string = str({"version":"20131101","logo":"http://image.aladin.co.kr/img/header/2011/aladin_logo_new.gif","title":"알라딘 베스트셀러 리스트 - 철학사","link":"http:\/\/www.aladin.co.kr\/shop\/common\/wbest.aspx?BestType=Bestseller&amp;BranchType=1&amp;CID=51441&amp;Year=2019&amp;Month=5&amp;Week=4&amp;partner=openAPI","pubDate":"Mon, 27 May 2019 10:33:33 GMT","totalResults":955,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":10,"query":"QueryType=BESTSELLER;CategoryId=51441;Year=2019;Month=5;Week=4","searchCategoryId":51441,"searchCategoryName":"철학사","item":[{"title":"처음 읽는 서양철학사 (개정증보판) - 서양의 대표 철학자 40인과 시작하는 철학의 첫걸음","link":"http:\/\/www.aladin.co.kr\/shop\/wproduct.aspx?ItemId=100442130&amp;partner=openAPI&amp;start=api","author":"안광복 (지은이)",}]})
as_dict = eval(as_string)
```

Comment: <ipython-input-1-4182957bfef7> in <module>
     58     decoding_bestseller = str(decoding_bestseller)
     59     as_string = str(decoding_bestseller)
---> 60     as_dict = eval(as_string)
     61 
     62     print(as_dict)

<string> in <module>

NameError: name 'false' is not defined

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. I literally copied the dict that you posted and it works for me. Try deleting the last comma which will make it a valid json and then use `json.loads(your_string)` as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Format of string you've provided is JSON. There's [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module in python, which has function [`loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads). This function will convert your string to `dict` object.

But there's one problem in string you provided:

> "author":"안광복 (지은이)"**>>>,<<<**}]}

This coma violates JSON stardart and causes error in decoder. If it's just typo, than just delete it. If source string really contains this, you should delete it from string before decoding (i.g. `string.replace(",}", "}")`)

How to decode:

```
import json

string = """{
   "version":"20131101",
   "logo":"http://image.aladin.co.kr/img/header/2011/aladin_logo_new.gif",
   "title":"알라딘 베스트셀러 리스트 - 철학사",
   "link":"http:\/\/www.aladin.co.kr\/shop\/common\/wbest.aspx?BestType=Bestseller&amp;BranchType=1&amp;CID=51441&amp;Year=2019&amp;Month=5&amp;Week=4&amp;partner=openAPI",
   "pubDate":"Mon, 27 May 2019 10:33:33 GMT",
   "totalResults":955,
   "startIndex":1,
   "itemsPerPage":10,
   "query":"QueryType=BESTSELLER;CategoryId=51441;Year=2019;Month=5;Week=4",
   "searchCategoryId":51441,
   "searchCategoryName":"철학사",
   "item":[
      {
         "title":"처음 읽는 서양철학사 (개정증보판) - 서양의 대표 철학자 40인과 시작하는 철학의 첫걸음",
         "link":"http:\/\/www.aladin.co.kr\/shop\/wproduct.aspx?ItemId=100442130&amp;partner=openAPI&amp;start=api",
         "author":"안광복 (지은이)"
      }
   ]
}"""

object_from_string = json.loads(string)

value_of_item = object_from_string["item"]

for value in value_of_item:
    for k, v in value.items():
        print(f"{k} = {v}")
```

Output:

```
title = 처음 읽는 서양철학사 (개정증보판) - 서양의 대표 철학자 40인과 시작하는 철학의 첫걸음
link = http://www.aladin.co.kr/shop/wproduct.aspx?ItemId=100442130&amp;partner=openAPI&amp;start=api
author = 안광복 (지은이)
```